# How to use tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory to load test dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am using `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` in my binary classification Mobilenet V2 model to split the dataset by defining training and validation subsets as following:

```
train_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(directory,
                                             shuffle=True,
                                             batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                             image_size=IMG_SIZE,
                                             validation_split=0.2,
                                             subset='training',
                                             seed=42)
validation_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(directory,
                                             shuffle=True,
                                             batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                             image_size=IMG_SIZE,
                                             validation_split=0.2,
                                             subset='validation',
                                             seed=42)
```

Now, I want to use `model.predict()` on a set of images to look at the predictions. How can I use `image_dataset_from_directory` considering that there won't be two different folders containing the respective classes but only one folder for which I want the predictions? In addition, what should be the parameters of the `image_dataset_from_directory` function now?

Comment: You need to have a separate directory containing test images. Then do the same thing you did for train/val datasets but with `shuffle=False` and without `validation_split`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by **@Djinn**, You can do it in the same way and no need to define `validation_split` while accessing the folder.

**For example**,
Suppose I have a `binary_data` folder inside the `dogs_cats/binary_data` folder where I have stored multiple class images (5-5 images for each cats and dogs), then you can give the path till `dogs_cats`.

This will automatically fetch all images inside the `binary_data` folder by stating class 1 where you can have multiple class images(binary - as per model) stored.

After training the model, you can pass this dataset in `model.predict()` and can check the predictions for each image.

**Please check the below code:**

```
test_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
          "/content/GoogleDrive/My Drive/MY WORK/dataset/dogs_cats/",
           shuffle=True,        #or False
           batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
           image_size=IMG_SIZE)
```

Output:

```
Found 10 files belonging to 1 classes.
```

and the predictions part:

```
predictions = model.predict(test_dataset)
predictions = tf.where(predictions < 0.5,0, 1)
print('Predictions:\n', predictions.numpy())
```

Output:

```
Predictions:
 [[0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]]
```

Note: Prediction's accuracy may depend on the model performance.

Comment: Good to know that. Happy Coding!